# Count ways 30 distinct books go to 6 students so each receives at most 7 books

Tags: combinatorics

What is a good method to number of ways to distribute $n=30$ distinct books to $m=6$ students so that each student receives at most $r=7$ books?

My observation is: If student $S_i$ receives $n_i$ books, the number of ways 
is: $\binom{n}{n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_m}$.

So answer is coefficient of $x^n$ in $n!(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{x^r}{r!})^m$.

For this case it means computing the coefficient of $x^{30}$ in $30!(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{x^7}{7!})^6$.

However, it's quite annoying to compute this coefficient without exponential function. Also if we change $(...)$ into $e^x-(\frac{x^8}{8!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}+\cdots)$, how can we handle $(\frac{x^8}{8!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}+\cdots)$ term?

Is there any good idea to handle this term for easier calculation?

Comment: Perhaps the [restricted compositions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61846/restricted-integer-compositions) of 30 into at most six parts with no part greater than 7 is the starting point for a computation.  [Henry Bottomley's online calculator](http://www.se16.info/js/partitionstest.htm) says there are 4802 possibilities, but only 46 partitions.  If the partitions are treated as "summaries" of the compositions, then it seems a spreadsheet would make this a tractable computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very easy, but calling $S(b,s,m)$ the number of distributions ($b$ books, $s$ students, $m$ maximum allowed for each) one could write:

$$S(b,s,m)= \sum_{k=0}^{\min(\lfloor b/m \rfloor,s)} {s \choose k} \frac{b!}{(m!)^k(b-m \,k)!} S(b-mk,s-k,m-1) $$

and compute recursively the values, with $S(b,s,m) = s^b$ for $s\le m$

Answer (score 1):

Since the Question does not state that each student must receive at least one book, I have included below in the 46 ways (that six nonnegative integers sum to 30) those with parts equal zero, limiting however summands not to exceed 7:

$$ 30 = s_1 + s_2 + s_3 + s_4 + s_5 + s_6 $$

such that $ 7 \ge s_1 \ge s_2 \ge s_3 \ge s_4 \ge s_5 \ge s_6 \ge 0 $. These solutions were generated by a short Prolog "program" (backtracking predicate):

```
/* genPartitionW(SumTotal,NumberOfParts,MaxPartSize,ListOfParts) */
genPartitionW(N,1,M,[N]) :- !, N >= 0, N =< M.
genPartitionW(N,K,M,[P|Ps]) :-
    Max is min(N,M),
    for(P,Max,1,-1),
    (   N > P*K
     -> fail
     ;  ( Km is K-1, Nm is N-P )
    ),
    genPartitionW(Nm,Km,P,Ps).
```

For each of these I created a row in a spreadsheet, computing in one cell the multinomial coefficient:

$$ \frac{30!}{s_1!\cdot s_2!\cdot s_3!\cdot s_4!\cdot s_5!\cdot s_6!} $$

and in another cell the multiplier that accounts for how many *weak compositions* correspond to that summation, which is $6!$ divided by the product of factorials of frequencies of parts (number of books allocated to one student).

For example, the first summation in our list is $30=7+7+7+7+2+0$.  The multinomial computation gives:

$$ \frac{30!}{7!\cdot 7!\cdot 7!\cdot 7!\cdot 2!\cdot 0!} = 205545481187904000 $$

and the orbit of weak compositions for that summation (arrangements of parts) has size:

$$ \frac{6}{4!\cdot 1!\cdot 1!} = 30 $$

The product of these is $205545481187904000\cdot 30 = 6166364435637120000$.

Due to the limited numerical precision of LibreOffice Calc (around 15 digits), I went back to programming (Amzi! Prolog supports arbitrary precision arithmetic) and got a grand total of 88,115,255,674,831,753,917,120 ways, or approximately 8.8115E+22.

**Ways to express 30 as sums (up to rearrangement) of 6 integers between 0 and 7**

```
7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 0
7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1
7, 7, 7, 6, 3, 0
7, 7, 7, 6, 2, 1
7, 7, 7, 5, 4, 0
7, 7, 7, 5, 3, 1
7, 7, 7, 5, 2, 2
7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 1
7, 7, 7, 4, 3, 2
7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3
7, 7, 6, 6, 4, 0
7, 7, 6, 6, 3, 1
7, 7, 6, 6, 2, 2
7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 0
7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1
7, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2
7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 2
7, 7, 6, 4, 3, 3
7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 1
7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 2
7, 7, 5, 5, 3, 3
7, 7, 5, 4, 4, 3
7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4
7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 0
7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 1
7, 6, 6, 6, 3, 2
7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 1
7, 6, 6, 5, 4, 2
7, 6, 6, 5, 3, 3
7, 6, 6, 4, 4, 3
7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 2
7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 3
7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4
7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3
7, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0
6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 1
6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 2
6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3
6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 2
6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3
6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4
6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 3
6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4
6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
```

Comment: Thanks anyway! I just solved this problem for large number by fourier transformation for polynomial multiplication and binary exponential calculation.

Comment: Excellent!  I think you should write it up as an Answer.