# Find number of restricted compositions of n

Tags: combinatorics

How to find the total number of compositions of n where no part is equal to 2.

More generally, how to find the number of compositions with restrictions such as this, where certain integers are not allowed?

Edit: How to find the recurrence relation - I am looking for a combinatorial proof . Solving in a different method, I got that the recurrence relation is:

$a_n +a_{n-2}=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}$

Thanks

Comment: Compositions? Do you mean integer [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29), like $5 = 1 + 1 + 3 = 1 + 2 + 2 = \ldots$?

Comment: @pjs36: [Compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29).

Comment: Thanks @BrianM.Scott, I had no idea that was a thing!

Comment: This was the subject of a 2003 paper by Phyllis Chinn and Sylvia Heubach, [Integer sequences related to compositions without 2's](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL6/Heubach/heubach5.html) in **J. Integer Seq. 6(2)** (electronic).  See the [OEIS entry A180177](https://oeis.org/A180177) for a tabulation of the number of compositions of $n$ with $k$ parts (none equal to $2$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not hard to find the generating functions, at least. Let $A$ be the set of allowable parts; then the number of compositions of $n$ into exactly $k$ allowable parts is easily seen to be

$$[x^n]\left(\sum_{a\in A}x^a\right)^k\;.$$

Since

$$\frac1{1-\sum_{a\in A}x^a}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\sum_{a\in A}x^a\right)^k\;,$$

the number of compositions of $n$ into allowable parts is

$$[x^n]\left(\frac1{1-\sum_{a\in A}x^a}\right)\;.$$

If $A=\Bbb Z^+\setminus\{2\}$, this is

$$[x^n]\left(\frac1{1-x-\sum_{a\ge 3}x^a}\right)=[x^n]\left(\frac1{1-x-\frac{x^3}{1-x}}\right)=[x^n]\left(\frac{1-x}{1-2x+x^2-x^3}\right)\;.$$

**Added:** This clearly implies that $a_n$, the number of allowable compositions of $n$, satisfies the recurrence

$$a_n=2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}\;.$$

To derive this combinatorially, suppose that $m_1+\ldots+m_k$ is a composition of $n$. If $m_1=1$, this composition is obtained by adding $1$ at the beginning of the allowable composition $m_2+\ldots+m_k$ of $n-1$. Conversely, every allowable composition of $n-1$ can be extended to an allowable composition of $n$ by adding $1$ at the beginning. Thus, $n$ has $a_{n-1}$ allowable compositions that begin with $1$.

If $m_1+m_2+\ldots+m_k$ is an allowable composition of $n-1$, we can also produce the composition $(m_1+1)+m_2+\ldots+m_k$ of $n$, which will be allowable if and only if $m_1\ne 1$. We just saw that $n-1$ has $a_{n-2}$ allowable compositions beginning with $1$, so this procedure of adding $1$ to the first term of a composition of $n-1$ produces $a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$ allowable compositions of $n$ that do not start with $1$.

However, this procedure does not produce any composition of $n$ that begins with $3$, since that would require starting with a non-allowable composition of $n-1$. To get the allowable compositions of $n$ that begin with $3$, we must start with an allowable composition of $n-3$ and add $3$ at the beginning. There are $a_{n-3}$ such compositions, so altogether we have

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})+a_{n-3}=2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}\;.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how would you find the recurrence relation from this? Please see the updated question above

Comment: @L887: You can read off the recurrence relation from the denominator of the generating function, but I’ve also added a combinatorial argument for it.

Comment: Amazing proof, thanks a lot!

Comment: @L887: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The "combinatorial proof" of the recurrence relation:

$$ a_n = 2a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} + a_{n-3} $$

as given by [Chinn and Heubach (2003)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL6/Heubach/heubach5.pdf), *Thm. 1*, is in agreement with what Brian M. Scott provides:

> The compositions of $n$ without $2$’s can be generated recursively from those of $n − 1$ by either appending a $1$ or by increasing the last summand by $1$. However, this process does not generate those compositions ending in $3$, which we generate separately by appending a $3$ to the compositions of $n − 3$. Furthermore, we must delete the compositions of $n − 1$ that
>   end in $1$, since increasing the terminal $1$ would produce a composition of $n$ that ends in $2$.  The number of such compositions corresponds to the number of compositions of $n − 2$.

As to more general problems "with restrictions such as this," there are many ways to ask about compositions with restrictions on values of parts.  The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) uses the phrase "A-restricted compositions" to mean those whose parts are in an *allowed* set of values $A$, while [some authors use the phrase](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL16/Eger/eger6.pdf) "S-restricted compositions" for *set* $S$ of allowed parts.

Problems [where the parts are restricted to an interval of (integer) values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61846/restricted-integer-compositions) were previously discussed here at Math.SE.  These problems can be reduced to ones where [the largest part does not exceed a fixed bound](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.0337.pdf), (Malandro, 2012), where the terminology $L$-compositions of $n$ is used for those with parts taken from a set $L$ of positive integers.

Finally there is on-going interest in efficient [algorithms for generating restricted integer compositions](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.1556.pdf).